# Inserting Data From Text File to SQL using BCP command

Tags: sql, batch-file, bcp

I am not too familiar with CMD/bat files, but I inherted a process from an previous coworker.  I have the following bcp command that I am trying to use to copy a substring of characters from a text file, using a format file (.fmt).  I am not getting any errors, but isn't copying over any rows.

--BCP Command

```
bcp tablename IN "location\txtfile.TXT" -f "C:\location\txtfile.FMT" -T -S ActualServerName -k -m 1000000
```

--Format File

```
11.0
5
1       SQLCHAR             0       28      "\t"     1     G1                   SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       10      "\t"     2     NPI                  SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       353     "\t"     3     G2                   SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       10      "\t"     4     Taxonomy     SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       439     "\r\n"   5     G3                SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
```

--Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE TableName](
[G1] [varchar](28) NULL,
[NPI] [varchar](10) NULL,
[G2] [varchar](315) NULL,
[Taxonomy] [varchar](10) NULL,
[G3] [varchar](439) NULL
)
```

Any suggestions?  Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction or show me why this isn't working.  Is this not enough information?

Comment: I wouldn't put my actual server name in the example. For future reference, change that to 'foo' or something else.

Comment: Checkout Erland's page on BCP: http://www.sommarskog.se/bulkload.html. Command and format file look fine. I'd look at the data your importing.